# Discord,py Global Ban Command

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make a global ban command that would basically ban a user from every discord server that my bot is in. I want to specify that my bot is made only for a community that owns multiple servers so it would be usefull to keep hackers/skids away from it by adding a global ban command.

This is my code. I am not getting any error when I do gban userid but still it doesn't ban the user. Any help?

```
@bot.command()
async def gban(ctx, user: discord.User):
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    await ctx.guild.ban(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is using `ctx.guild.ban`, think about it, it will only ban the user from the current guild, but run it in a for loop. Here is what you need to do:

```py
@bot.command()
async def gban(ctx, user: discord.User):
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    await guild.ban(user)
```